# Deploying a Tensorboard plugin

Tags: python, plugins, tensorboard, bazel

According to this official Tensorboard plugin example:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example

the only way to use a custom Tensorboard plugin is to build a custom Tensorboard that includes that plugin. It seems very bizarre (I guess a much better way to intergate a custom plugin would be to register it somehow with the "standard" Tensorboard, or to pass its name/path as an argument to Tensorboard). It's a strange approach, but I could live with it. What really bothers me is that from the above example it looks like the only way to start a custom Tensorboard is to use 'bazel run' command

```
bazel run //greeter_tensorboard -- --logdir=/tmp/greeter_demo
```

Or maybe I am wrong, and it is possible to start a custom TensorBoard without Bazel?  I am new to both Python and Tensorboard, so I could not figure out a different way to start it. Unfortunately, the README.md that comes with the example does not say much about deploying Tensorboard plugins, and instead provides a link to Tensorboard README and to Bazel documentation. But I was unable to find any useful info there regarding deploying plugins and custom tensorboards.

> **Integration**
>
> Once you have a plugin (or, more realistically, as you are developing
>   it), you will want to use it inside TensorBoard. To do that, we
>   recommend you fork this repository; it has everything set up for you.
>
> Basically, the way you integrate a new plugin is by creating a custom
>   TensorBoard build. The custom build needs to change two things:
>
> 1. It needs to use its own main.py file, which imports the standard TensorBoard plugins, and adds a new one on the backend.
> 2. It needs to provide its own index.html file, which imports the new TensorBoard plugin frontend, and registers it as a dashboard.
>
> If you want to really understand what’s going on with the integration,
>   you’ll need to understand Bazel, our build system. You can read the
>   Bazel docs and also our compilation of useful tips.

If this is the only way to start a custom tensorboard, this means every user of my custom tensorboard would have to install Bazel, and build a custom tensorboard from C++ and Python sources. But I could not even get Bazel to build this Greeter sample on Windows because VC15 compiler (the one that comes with Visual Studio 2017) cannot compile C++ used in TensorBoard (I guess because VC does not fully support modern C++ standard). I was only able to build it on Linux.
So my question is: how exactly should custom tensorboards be distributed and started? Is it possible to do it without Bazel?

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out how to create a distribution of a custom Greeter demo tensorboard and to run it without Bazel. Let's say Greeter demo tensorboard code was cloned into **~/tensorboard-plugin-example**. After building the plugin and the tensorboard using the commands:

```
bazel run //greeter_plugin:greeter_demo
bazel run //greeter_tensorboard -- --logdir=/tmp/greeter_demo
```

1. Copy **greeter_tensorboard** directory from **~/tensorboard-plugin-example** to **~/**
2. Copy **~/tensorboard-plugin-example/greeter_plugin** directory into **~/greeter_tensorboard**
3. Copy the file **assets.zip** from **~/tensorboard-plugin-example/bazel-bin/greeter_tensorboard** to **~/greeter_tensorboard**

You can now start your custom Greeter tensorboard using the command:

```
python ~/greeter_tensorboard/main.py --logdir=/tmp/greeter_demo
```

It is assumed that the test data has been generated in **/tmp/greeter_demo** directory by running

```
bazel run //greeter_plugin:greeter_demo
```

command.